# Missing InheritedExport in Microsoft.Composition

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-runtime, mef

Seems there is no `InheritedExport` attribute in [MEF for web and Windows Store apps](https://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Composition). What can I do to avoid all pain I'll be getting by add `Export(typeof(IMyInterface))` to each and every implementation of this interface?

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any samples to point you at but have you tried using the ConventionBuilder? You should be able to setup a convention that says export all types that implement IMyInterface which would essentially give you similar behavior as InheritedExport.